# Alternative to timeout socket

Tags: python, xml, sockets, xmpp

Is there an alternative technique of `timeout` to interrupt communication with a server in case it has received all the messages?

Let me explain, I want to communicate through an SSL socket with a server (XMPP) unknown to me. The communication is done through XML messages.
For each request I can receive one or more response messages of different types. Or a single message that is sent in multiple chunks. Therefore I create a loop to receive all messages related to a request from the server. So I do not know the number and the size of messages for each request a priori. Once the messages are finished, the client waits for no more responses from the Server to stop listening (i.e., it waits for the `timeout`). However, this results in a long wait (e.g., for each request I have to wait 2s which at the end of the communication could be as long as 1 minute for all requests).

Is there a faster way to stop listening when we have received all the messages for each request?

I attach here my code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl. ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
sock.connect((hostname, port))

sock.timeout(2)

#example for a generic unique message request
sock.sendall(message.encode())

data = “”
while True:
  try:
    response = sock.recv(1024)
    if not response: break
    data += response.decode()
  except socket.timeout:
    break
```

Comment: usually the protocol tells you how many messages you have to wait for. What is the request and response you are getting?

Comment: If you don't know the protocol (as you say the server is unknown to you) then you are stuck with guessing, and timeouts are one way to guess.

Comment: Since it's XMPP are you sure the messages you are getting are responses to your command - and not completely unrelated messages?

Comment: For example, if I send:`<?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream to="tr1.pvp.net" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">`
to open a stream, i receive 2 message for response:
`<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='770556964' from='tr1.pvp.net' version='1.0'>` and `<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>...</mechanisms></stream:features>`

Comment: But if I send `<iq id="_xmpp_session1" type="set"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>` to open a session, i receive a single response message: `<iq type='result' id='_xmpp_session1'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'>...</session></iq>`

Comment: Or I can send a request (such as receiving the list of all contacts), I receive a single response sent in multiple chunks (since the response may exceed the number of bytes requested).

Answer (score 1):

You know how much data to expect because of the protocol.

The [XMPP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120) says ([section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.2)) what the start of a stream looks like; ([section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.3)) tells you about stream negotiation process which the <stream:features> tag is used for. Don't understand them yet? [Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.1) tells you about what a stream is and how it works.

In one comment, you complained about receiving a response in multiple chunks. This is absolutely normal in TCP because TCP does not care about chunks. TCP can split up a 1kB message into 1000 1-byte chunks if it feels like it (usually it doesn't feel like it). So you must keep receiving chunks until you see the end of the message.

Actually, XMPP is not even a request-response protocol. The server can send you messages at any time, which are not responses to something you sent, for example it could tell you that someone said "hello" to you. So you might send an IQ request, but the next message you receive might not be an IQ response, it might be a message saying that your friend is now online. You know which message is the response because: the message type is IQ; the 'type' is 'result' or 'error'; and the 'id' is the same as in the request. [Section 8.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-8.2.3).

Comment: But i don’t understand how can i know the numbers of messages expected for a single request.

Comment: @Wag for an IQ in XMPP? The number is 1. It's always 1.

Comment: Yep, but for example, if i send a presence a receive a lot of messages.

Comment: @Wag what messages?

Comment: One message for user online

Comment: @Wag can you show the messages?